# Deploying projects with renv in offline environment

Tags: r, renv

What is the correct procedure to deploy packages using `renv` to an offline machine?

We have an internal CRAN-like repository, which is configured via `options(repos = list(cran = "http://our.repo.url"))` on both the development machine and the deployment machine. It is specified in `renv.lock`. The `renv` package itself is installed on both machines, and both are the same version (1.14).

After deployment, after starting R in the project directory, it hangs for a while, and returns an error:

```
# Bootstrapping renv 0.14.0--------
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/:
  cannot open URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
* Downloading renv 0.14.0 ... FAILED
```

How do I tell `renv` to either copy itself from the system library, or install from the internal repository?

Copying from the system library would be of course the preferred course of action, to save time compiling.

Comment: Shouldn't `CRAN` be written in all capitals? Looks like your renv is still pointing to the original CRAN repository.

Comment: @AllDownhillFromHere, names in `options("repos")` are optional and they don't mean much (afaict).

Comment: Yes, capitalization there doesn't seem to matter in this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to file an issue at https://github.com/rstudio/renv/issues since I think `renv` doesn't currently support loading the `renv` package from a non-project library path via the autoloader.

That said, you should be able to move forward by disabling the `renv` auto-loader. Before launching R, you can set the environment variable:

```
RENV_ACTIVATE_PROJECT = FALSE
```

Then, when R is started, the `renv` auto-loader (run via `source("renv/activate.R")` in the project `.Rprofile`) will be disabled. You can then later load `renv` from whichever library path is appropriate, and call `renv::load()` to manually load a particular project.

(The other alternative to setting that environment variable is simply removing the `renv` auto-loader from the project `.Rprofile`.)

Comment: Thanks! BTW more generally, can `renv` make use of already available & compiled packages in `.libPaths()` to save time re-compiling? I guess the answer is no, probably because there is no guarantee that an installed package doesn't include hardcoded paths somewhere?

Comment: BTW, in case someone else is reading this: looks like setting the env. variable this way is necessary at deployment time to activate and install packages into `renv/library`; subsequently the project can be run on the deployment system as normal, with autoloading enabled.